# Why does this example TCP Server throw exceptions if it's not closed?

Tags: tcp, groovy, client

*This is written in Groovy by the way*

I haven't messed with my TCP Server script in awhile and decided that I want it to stay open and continue listening even after it is used rather than only be good for one use. However, when I do this, it throws an exception and then closes the script anyways.

My example script is as follows:

**TCP Server**

```
def server = new ServerSocket(2000)

println("Waiting for connection")


    server.accept() { socket ->
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->

        w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))
        String message = "Connection was successful"

            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))

        while(true) {
        if(message !=null) {
            sendMessage(message)
            message = null
        }

        String a = r.readLine()

        if(a.equals("name"))
            message = "Bob"
        else if(a.equals("date"))
            message = new Date()
        else if(a.equals("ip")) 
            message = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
        else if(a.equals("quit")) {
            server.close()
            return
        } else 
            message = "$a command unknown"
        }
        }
    }

def sendMessage(String msg) {
    println("Sending: >" + msg + "<")
    w.writeLine(msg)
    w.flush();
}
```

The issue comes in the client. If I use the `quit` command, then it closes the server once the other commands are done. However if I remove `quit` from the commands then the server attempts to stay open, throws an exception, and then closes the server anyways.

**TCP Client**

```
def commands 
def answers
def requestSocket
def r
def w

String host = "filipekdt7"
commands = ["name",
        "date",
        "ip",
        "quit"]   //If I take out "quit" then the exceptions get thrown, but I want to leave my server script running

answers = [commands.size]

requestSocket = new Socket(host, 2000)

r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestSocket.getInputStream()))
w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(requestSocket.getOutputStream()))

String message = r.readLine()
println "Server >" + message

for(int n = 0; n < commands.size; n++) {
    sendMessage(commands[n],w)
    answers[n] = r.readLine()
}

w.flush()
w.close()


public String sendMessage(def msg, def w) {
    w.write(msg+"\r\n")
    w.flush()
    println "Client>" + msg
}
```

Does anyone know a way to keep the server script running? I think I'm just over looking something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your server code as:

```
def server = new ServerSocket(2000)
println("Waiting for connection")

while (true) {
    server.accept() { socket ->
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            def w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))
            String message = "Connection was successful"
            def r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))

            while (true) {
                if (message !=null) {
                    sendMessage(message, w)
                    message = null
                }

                String a = r.readLine()
                if (a == null) {
                    socket.close()
                    println "Client disconnected"
                    return
                } else if (a.equals("name")) {
                    message = "Bob"
                } else if (a.equals("date")) {
                    message = new Date()
                } else if (a.equals("ip")) {
                    message = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
                } else if (a.equals("quit")) {
                    server.close()
                    return
                } else { 
                    message = "$a command unknown"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def sendMessage(msg, writer) {
    println("Sending: >" + msg + "<")
    writer.writeLine(msg.toString())
    writer.flush();
}
```

Notice how the `ServerSocket` repeatedly `accept`s connections in a `while` loop. This keeps the server script running.

You were getting the exception earlier because you were attempting to send a message to a client that had disconnected from the server. To fix that you should verify that the command read from the client is valid (i.e. `a != null`), before attempting to send a response back.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Binil Thomas! You were absolutely correct. I appreciate you explaining why it was throwing the exception.